# Create a javascript object which looks like a list or object inside a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

i am trying to build a javascript object with two different arrays.  below are my two arrays
Array1 :

```
[{master:'1',total:123,price:34},
{master:'1',total:323,price:45},
{master:'2',total:555,price:22}]
```

Array2 :

```
[{master:'1',quantity:10},
{master:'2',quantity:20},
{master:'3',quantity:30}]
```

i want to merge above two arrays like below array

```
[{master:'1',
   quantity:10,
   child:[
    {total:123,price:34},
    {total:323,price:45}
   ]
  },
  {master:'2',
    quantity:20,
    child:[
     {total:555,price:22}
    ]
  },
  {
   master:'3',
   quantity=30
   }
}]
```

i am confused to build this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach,

```js
const arr1=[{master:"1",total:123,price:34},{master:"1",total:323,price:45},{master:"2",total:555,price:22},],arr2=[{master:"1",quantity:10},{master:"2",quantity:20},{master:"3",quantity:30},];

const masters = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.master] = curr;
    return acc;
}, {});

arr1.forEach(({ master, ...rest }) => {
    const obj = masters[master];
    if (!obj.child) {
        obj.child = [];
    }

    obj.child.push({ ...rest });
});

const result = Object.values(masters);
console.log(result);
```